# How can send byte by byte of a video from producer and collect each byte and convert it to the array

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, video-streaming

This is producer config.

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootStrapServers;

    public Map<String, Object> producerConfig() {
        HashMap<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootStrapServers);
        props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_REQUEST_SIZE_CONFIG, "20971520");
        return props;

    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {

        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, String>(producerConfig());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory) {
        return new KafkaTemplate<String, String>(producerFactory);

    }
}
```

This is consumer config

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootStrapServers;

    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfig() {
        HashMap<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootStrapServers);
        props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer");
        return props;

    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {

        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, String>(consumerConfig());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> factory() {

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

This is kafka template.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

@Service
public class KafkaSender {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;
    String kafkaTopic = "testTopic";
    public void send() {
        byte[] array = null;

        try {
            array = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("Test.webm"));
            String kafkaTopic = "testTopic";
            String encoded = java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(array);
            kafkaTemplate.send(kafkaTopic, encoded);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is listener.

```
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Base64;

@Component
public class Listener {

    @KafkaListener(topics = "testTopic", groupId = "foo")
    public void listenGroupFoo(String message){

            byte[] decoded = java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(message);

        try {
            FileOutputStream out;
            out = new FileOutputStream("video1.mp4");
            out.write(decoded);
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }
}
```

Currently I am sending whole byte array but it there is size limitation on kafka I could not sent larger size for eg: 1GB
Please let me know how can we implementation so that i can send byte by byte of a video from producer and collect at consumer and convert all the bytes to a array.

Comment: Kafka isn't really a proper solution for this. RTMP protocol would be better

Answer (score 0):

> send byte by byte of a video from producer

Literally? Don't use StringSerializer. You'd loop over the array and use ByteArraySerializer

```
byte[] array = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("Test.webm"));
String kafkaTopic = "testTopic";
           
for (byte b : bytes) {
    kafkaTemplate.send(kafkaTopic, new byte[] {b});
}
```

But

1. You can only ever produce one file into the same topic at a time - multiple producers will have mixed file bytes
2. You must modify Kafka producer properties to use transactions, no retries, and only one in flight request max. Otherwise, bytes get dropped, duplicated, or reordered.
3. Your topic can only have one partition. Otherwise, bytes get reordered

Now, you could chunk the file into larger byte slices, but then re-ordering matters even more.

As far as the consumer goes - there's no straightforward way to know which byte is the end of the file/stream, but you'd need to have some if statement in the listener/poll loop.

---

Ultimately, Kafka is not designed for file transfers or A/V streaming, and largest reasonable record size would only be a few MB.